# Remover gradient

Tags: android, android-layout

No meu `side_nav_bar` a coloração está definida como `gradient`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:centerColor="#009688"
    android:endColor="#00695C"
    android:startColor="#4DB6AC"
    android:type="linear" />
```

Como eu removo o gradient para que fique só uma cor apenas ?

Comment: Para facilitar a resposta coloque o xml do side_nav_bar.

Comment: @ramaral editado.

Comment: Esse é o xml do gradiente. O que eu quero ver é como você atribui esse gradiente ao side_nav_bar.

Comment: @ramaral talvez eu não entendi bem, mas este é o conteúdo do side_nav_bar.xml

Comment: @ramaral consegui o que eu queria, é só trocar o gradiant por solid :)

Comment: @Douglas Coloque sua solução como resposta. Pode ajudar alguém com a mesma dúvida no futuro.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida pronto.

Answer (score 0):

A solução era simples, bastava trocar o gradiend por solid ficando assim:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid
    android:color="#00695C" />
```